# SQL to show overlapping time periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, overlap

How to check in Postgresql 9.2 (SQL command), if in the timestamp records there is some period overlapping others from same id_user. I need to correct an existing table.

For example, a query show the rows 1,3 and 4.

```
id | id_user | timedate0           | timedate2
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2020-04-20 12:00:00 | 2020-04-20 14:00:00
2  | 1       | 2020-04-20 17:00:00 | 2020-04-20 19:30:00
3  | 1       | 2020-04-20 14:30:00 | 2020-04-20 15:40:00
4  | 1       | 2020-04-20 13:00:00 | 2020-04-20 15:00:00
5  | 1       | 2020-04-21 13:00:00 | 2020-04-21 14:00:00
6  | 1       | 2020-04-21 14:00:00 | 2020-04-21 15:00:00
```

Comment: Consider updating to a current version of Postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.timedate0 < t.timedate2 and
                    t2.timedate2 > t.timedate0 and
                    t2.id_user = t.id_user and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

Comment: @misterxis . . . I fixed that.

Comment: This can be written simpler using range types and the "overlaps" operator `&&`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . I just never remember if the overlaps operator includes the end points, so I write the logic explicitly.